# How to save a curl download in a std::string?

Tags: c++, curl

I know I can call system("curl path-LJO") from a c++ program to download a file and save it in the current directory and then I can use the STL to save it to a std::string. But is there a way to save it directly in a std::string? I know abot https://github.com/curl/curl but I was wondering: is any specifier in the curl command that does that? If not, what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: libcurl will let you invoke curl without creating a separate process, then you don't have to worry about interprocess communication

Comment: You could redirect the subprocess's output to a pipe and read the output from it.  How you do that is platform-dependent though.  See `popen` or `fork`/`exec` on POSIX systems and `CreateProcess` on Windows.  There aren't any subprocess management facilities in the C++ standard library outside of the very limited `system` function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library in your code. You can use the [`CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html) and [`CURLOPT_READDATA`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READDATA.html) options to setup a callback that saves the received data directly to your `std::string` variable.

Comment: so I must use a library? No way to do it just with OS cmd commands?

Comment: @user2000 You can write the code using low level sockets if you want. But it is a little more involved https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html (You'll need to study up on `HTTP` protocol too.)

Comment: @user2000 there is no way a `cmd` command can write directly to a variable inside your process. But there are some workarounds, like Miles mentioned. But `curl.exe` is just a wrapper for the `libcurl` library, so cut out the middleman and use `libcurl` directly. Sure, you could use sockets directly, but then you have to implement the HTTP protocol manually, and that is not trivial to do. `libcurl`has already done the hard work. Or use any of a number of pre-made HTTP libraries that are readily available.