# Saving download file from curl with a writer function in a char* buffer

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am downloading a file with curl using the write data function and I am trying to save the file in memory. I want to convert the downloaded file without saving it onto my disk and preferably in a char* buffer. How exactly would I go about this?

Comment: Related: [c++ - How to save a curl download in a std::string? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908437/how-to-save-a-curl-download-in-a-stdstring)

Comment: The libcurl documentation for [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) provides an example of this EXACT task.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: The curl project already wrote that code for you: [getinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)